# How to configure Jersey 3x to work with embedded Jetty 9x

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, jetty, embedded-jetty, jersey-3.0

I am trying to upgrade to Jersey 3x from 2.35 to work with Jetty 9x embedded so that I may use the Asynchronous Server API that is supported in 3x. The current maven pom.xml is:

```xml
<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.35</jersey.version>
    <!--jersey.version>3.0.0</jersey.version-->
    <jetty.version>9.4.28.v20200408</jetty.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<!--Test Dependencies-->
</dependencies>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
       <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
       <version>${jetty.version}</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
       <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
       <version>${jetty.version}</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
       <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
       <version>${jetty.version}</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
       <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
       <version>${jersey.version}</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
       <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
       <version>${jersey.version}</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
       <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
       <version>${jersey.version}</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Now when I change the version to 3.0.0 I get dependency errors. I am trying to follow the Chapter 2 of **Modules and dependencies** of the jersey user guide but I am not able to resolve to the correct dependencies.

What are the correct jersey dependencies to reference in the POM for Jersey 3x ?

Comment: It won't work. You will probably have to use Jetty 11. Jersey 3.x uses the new Jakarta namespace. I think Jetty starts supporting that in 11.

Comment: Thanks Paul, this is unfortunate, we currently support Java 8 and so moving to Jetty 11x will be a problem. You can put your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @kimathie Jetty 9 is likely going to go EOL in March 2022 when Java 8 support moves from Premier to Extended (and all updates to the Java runtime gets locked behind support contracts, meaning no more publicly accessible JDK/JRE runtimes).  Every past Jetty version has gone EOL at this transition point as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jersey 3.x requires the new `jakarta.*` namespace from the [Jakarta EE 9 "Big Bang"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66368511/775715).

Jetty 9.x is Servlet 3.1.0 which is `javax.servlet.*` namespace.

You have to use Jetty 11 for the Jakarta EE 9 namespace changes.