# Running Java Maven project using Jetty docker image

Tags: java, docker, maven, jetty

I am having a simple java maven project which generates some user Ids for a given `GET` request. I am using `javax.servlet` package.

Everything works fine when I am packaging and deploying the `war` file in local `jetty` server.

However things are not working when I am using the `docker jetty` image and deploying the `war` file. I am getting the below error

```
MacBook-Pro-3:UIDGenerators unbxd$ docker run 0xvoila/uid-generator:latest 
2022-07-03 17:50:09.448:INFO :oejs.Server:main: jetty-11.0.11; built: 2022-06-21T21:42:55.454Z; git: 58487315cb75e0f5c81cc6fa50096cbeb3b9554e; jvm 17.0.3+7
2022-07-03 17:50:09.523:INFO :oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:///var/lib/jetty/webapps/]
2022-07-03 17:50:10.234:INFO :oejss.DefaultSessionIdManager:main: Session workerName=node0
2022-07-03 17:50:10.291:WARN :oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@4f67eb2a{Archetype Created Web Application,/uid-generator,file:///tmp/jetty-0_0_0_0-8080-uid-generator_war-_uid-generator-any-15856705197144621036/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{/var/lib/jetty/webapps/uid-generator.war}
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:524)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:427)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:421)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
```

Here is my `pom.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.amit.system</groupId>
  <artifactId>UIDGenerators</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>UIDGenerators Maven Webapp</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>uid-generator</finalName>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>

<!--        <plugin>-->
<!--          <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>-->
<!--          <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>-->
<!--          <version>9.4.28.v20200408</version>-->
<!--        </plugin>-->

      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Here is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM maven as build

COPY src /home/app/src
COPY pom.xml /home/app
RUN mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml clean package


FROM jetty:latest
COPY --from=build /home/app/target/uid-generator.war /var/lib/jetty/webapps
CMD java -jar "$JETTY_HOME/start.jar"
```

I tried to debug myself and it seems like `javax. servlet` is not present in the `jetty` docker image. But in my `pom.xml` file I had given `javax.servlet` as dependencies.

Can anyone help me with the solution.

UPDATED

Here is the java code

```
package org.amit.system;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class UIDGenerator extends HttpServlet {

    int sequence = 0;
    final static int sequenceBits = 12; // max is 4096
    final static int maxSequence = (int)Math.pow(2, sequenceBits) - 1;

    final static int nodeId = 11;
    final static int nodeBits = 10; // max is 1024

    public synchronized int generateSequence(long runningMillisecond){

        this.sequence = this.sequence + 1;

        if (this.sequence >= maxSequence && runningMillisecond == System.currentTimeMillis()){
            waitOneMillisecond(runningMillisecond);
            this.sequence = 0;
        }

        return this.sequence;
    }

    private void waitOneMillisecond(long runningMillisecond){

        while(runningMillisecond == System.currentTimeMillis()){
            continue;
        }
    }

    public int generateNodeId(){
        return this.nodeId;
    }

    public void run(){
        int nodeNumber = this.generateNodeId();

        long epoch = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int sequence = this.generateSequence(epoch);

//        System.out.println("Echo before shift " + epoch);
        epoch = epoch << (this.nodeBits + this.sequenceBits);
        epoch = epoch | nodeNumber << this.sequenceBits;
        epoch = epoch | sequence;

        System.out.println("Echo after shift " + epoch);
    }



    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException
    {
        int nodeNumber = this.generateNodeId();

        long epoch = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int sequence = this.generateSequence(epoch);

        epoch = epoch << (this.nodeBits + this.sequenceBits);
        epoch = epoch | nodeNumber << this.sequenceBits;
        epoch = epoch | sequence;

        response.getOutputStream().print("Echo after shift " + epoch);

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this error is arising from the docker issue?
The scripts seem fine to me, may be some problem in the code ?
Can you post the java code if possible ?
Also can you let us know how are you running the docker image ?

Comment: @RathanNaik : I have updated the java code. I am just building my docker file like `docker build -t latest .`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jetty 9 is at End of Community Support.

See: https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/7958

You should upgrade, to at least Jetty 10.

The problem you have is the combination of `jetty-11.0.11` and `javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet`.

Jetty 11 supports Servlet 5.0, which underwent the Jakarta "Big Bang" and changed namespace to `jakarta.servlet.*`

See Past Question for details (including table in accepted answer for support levels for the combination of Jetty version, Servlet Spec version, EE governing body, and Servlet namespace)

- [Jetty 11 Doesn't Detect Servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66361859/jetty-11-doesnt-detect-servlets)

Comment: It is the answer to the answer I provided below. Thank you very much.. Let me try changing javax to jakarta and check if with docker image jetty:latest it will work or not. I will accept this answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Problem got resolved for me. Actually problem was with my jetty image. Instead of using `FROM jetty:latest`, I should be using `FROM jetty:9-jre8-openjdk` then only `classes and servlet jars` would be available for my application.

Here it the complete `Dockerfile`

```
FROM maven as build

COPY src /home/app/src
COPY pom.xml /home/app
RUN mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml clean package


FROM jetty:9-jre8-openjdk
COPY --from=build /home/app/target/root.war /var/lib/jetty/webapps
EXPOSE 8080
CMD java -jar "$JETTY_HOME/start.jar"
```

Comment: While working with jetty inside docker, I found that pulling the jetty copy directly from maven central and creating jetty base etc. within the docker container was much more easier and helpful to manage. It was very tough working with jetty configurations when I tried to use the ready images.