# Use Jetty server inside a JavaFX / Swing app

Tags: java, swing, javafx, embedded-jetty

I´m trying to implement a Jetty Server inside a Swing / JavaFX application.
There is a similar project with Tomcat:
https://www.beyondjava.net/how-to-wrap-bootsfaces-or-jsf-in-general-as-a-native-desktop-application

Now I´m trying to change this to Jetty.
This is in my main code (instead tomcat)

```
public void run() throws Exception {
    Server server = new Server(8080);

    Path basePath = new File("src/main/webapp/").toPath().toRealPath();

    WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
    context.setContextPath("/");

    // Configuring from Development Base
    context.setBaseResource(new PathResource(basePath.resolve("src/main/webapp")));
    // Add webapp compiled classes & resources (copied into place from
    // src/main/resources)
    Path classesPath = basePath.resolve("target/webapp/WEB-INF/classes");
    context.setExtraClasspath(classesPath.toAbsolutePath().toString());
    server.setDumpAfterStart(true);

    server.setHandler(context);

    server.start();
}
```

In the pom.xml I´ve added this:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.48.v20220622</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.48.v20220622</version>
        </dependency>
```

If I start the Main function the Webapp (index.xhtml) is not showing.
Ijust got:

[image]

Here the structure:
[image]

Any idea what is wrong?

Here the web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <!--param-value>Production</param-value -->
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- The BootsFaces_THEME context-param controls the loading of the Themes -->


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>


    <!-- Map following files to the JSF servlet -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

The faces-config.xml is currently empty

Comment: What exactly is your question? Something not working, any errors, etc.?

Comment: I tried already to have "index.xhtml" and "index.jsf" but still the same issue... In my web.xml I have this, so I think it doesn´t matter: <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

Comment: When you start your Swing app, check what is the current working directory (system property user.dir). Then check if your relative paths for Jetty resources are reachable.

Comment: do you have an coding example?

Comment: Please copy/paste your `WEB-INF/web.xml` as well into the question.

Comment: @Joakim ok, I did

Answer (score 2):

Note: Jetty 9.4.x is now at End of Community Support.
I would recommend upgrading to Jetty 10.x or Jetty 11.x as soon as you are able to. ([Pay attention to namespace when making your decision](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66368511/775715))

See https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/7958

The first thing that jumps out at me is that there is a problem with your baseResource reference.

```java
Path basePath = new File("src/main/webapp/").toPath().toRealPath();

context.setBaseResource(new PathResource(basePath.resolve("src/main/webapp")));
```

That will result in a baseResource of `src/main/webapp/src/main/webapp`.

Your console / logs would show this as well.

Change it to ...

```java
context.setBaseResource(new PathResource(basePath));
```

The next thing I notice is that you have JSP files, to enable JSP support requires some extra steps.

If using Jetty 10+ you'll need the following dependencies.

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>apache-jsp</artifactId>
  <version>10.0.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>10.0.11</version>
</dependency>
```

If using Jetty 9 or older, you'll also need to setup a whole mess of initialization manually with Server `Configuration`, webapp `Configuration`, a few properties to tell jetty where to scan for implementations in the server or webapp classloaders, manually add a few ServletContainerInitializers to enable JSP properly, etc.  (it's easier to just upgrade to Jetty 10)

https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-jsp

Comment: If I change that to your approach, I´m gettng: HTTP ERROR 503 Service Unavailable and in the logs some other errors: SCHWERWIEGEND: Unable to obtain InjectionProvider from init time FacesContext. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?
Jul 09, 2022 1:35:04 PM javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance getFactory
SCHWERWIEGEND: Die Anwendung wurde bei Systemstart nicht einwandfrei initialisiert, Factory konnte nicht gefunden werden: javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory.

Comment: Thnak you.... I´ve updated to 10.0.11.... and now I´m getting this error after I start the application inside the SWT app:  "The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection."

Comment: That means you need to use `https`, not `http`.

Comment: how can I change that? I mean I´m using localhost?

Comment: Joakim, I´m using JSF not JSP...

Comment: ok, I fixed that Issue with https... it´s a bug in elipse... but still I got 503 error